# Infinite decimals to prove that intervals are equipotent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Use infinite decimals to prove that the real interval(0,10) is equipotent to its subset, (0,1).

I've deduced through infinite decimals that the interval (0,1) is uncountable, but I'm unsure how to prove that it is as uncountable as the interval (0,10).
Can I just say that (0,1) $\subset$ (0,10), thus (0,10) is also uncountable, but this does not prove they're equipotent?

Comment: What happens if you produce a bijection between the two sets?

Comment: @ConMan That's what I'm trying to prove, as that would show that they're equipotent.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that two sets are uncountable does not suffice to prove that they are equipotent. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ and its power set are both uncountable, but they are not equipotent.

What I would suggest doing for this problem is finding a bijection $(0,10) \to (0,1)$. There is a very simple one, which doesn't require any consideration of decimal expansions of real numbers.

Comment: $\frac{x}{10}$ would suffice but the question explicitly asks me to use infinite decimals?

Comment: @theman: That seems silly, but fair enough - in that case just move the decimal point by one place to the left. (But then this is the same as dividing by 10.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.